# Robot framework: Treating escape value \ when stored another keyword (POST API call)

Tags: syntax, escaping, robotframework

I am trying to automate API testing using robot framework and the requests library.

One of the values I need to store and use in a following API calls is an encrypt key which typically contains an unknown number of backslashes.

The key is retrieved as follows:

> ${response}       POST On Session    session Name    #the line continues with the rest of the input

and:
Set Suite Variable    $encrypt_key    ${response.json()}[encryptKey]

This key will then be passed in the body of another API call with other similarly obtained variables e.g:

> ${data}    Create Dictionary    document=${document_b64}
> fileName=${output_name}       encryptKey=${encrypt_key}

and:

> ${response}    POST On Session     json=${data}

The problem is the true key is something like: }951h9/mNzOgZ**\**eA/FV*l+rib)m6io:(

While what robot passes as input is something like:

> }951h9/mNzOgZ**\\**eA/FV*l+rib)m6io:(

Is there any way to solve this?

I will also take suggestions to improve the title, I know it is not the best.

Could not think of any way to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to manipulate the key?

> While what robot passes as input is something like: }951h9/mNzOgZ**\\**eA/FV*l+rib)m6io:(

When Robot Framework (actually, Python) shows a value in human readable format, adds the double \, but internally the value is the same. Note: this is my personal interpretation.

But to avoid this, you can encode/decode or use "raw" or byte strings.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I solved with
'code' {encrypt_key.replace("\\","\\\\")}

Answer (score 0):

When I call the problematic variable in following code I use

`${encrypt_key.replace("\\","\\\\")}`